# Merge images as CALayer with applied CIFilter on video in swift 5

Tags: swift

Am developing a video editor app in which i applied filter on run time and applying stickers, text and overlay with the help of UIImageView, But my problem is when i want to merge and export these things simultaneously its not working, so i have to export twice time. Firstly i have to export video with applied CIFilter and get URL then from this URL i have to merge and applied other UIImageView as CALayer. It take too much time, Please help here is my code what am doing -

```
//MARK: Apply the selected filter to the video
    func applyFilterToVideo(opacity: CGFloat) {
      
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self, let selectedFilter = self.selectedFilterType else { return }
            
            let videoComposition = AVVideoComposition(asset: (self.avplayer.currentItem?.asset)!) { (request) in
                let source = request.sourceImage.clampedToExtent()
                selectedFilter.setValue(source, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
                selectedFilter.setValue(opacity, forKey: kCIInputSaturationKey)
                
                if let outputImage = selectedFilter.outputImage {
                    request.finish(with: outputImage, context: nil)
                } else {
                    request.finish(with: source, context: nil)
                }
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                
                self.avplayer.currentItem?.videoComposition = videoComposition
            }
        }
    }
```

```
//MARK: SAVE VIDEO WITH APPLIED FILTER
    func convertVideoAndSaveTophotoLibrary(url: URL) {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            
            let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url as URL)
            
            let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            let savedoutputURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Filterd.mov")
            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: savedoutputURL)
            
            let export = AVAssetExportSession(asset: videoAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
            
            if avplayer.isMuted {
                let audioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
                let audioMixInputParameters = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first)
                audioMixInputParameters.setVolume(0.0, at: CMTime.zero)
                audioMix.inputParameters = [audioMixInputParameters]
                export?.audioMix = audioMix
            }
            
            export!.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
            export!.outputURL = savedoutputURL
            export!.videoComposition = avplayer.currentItem?.videoComposition
            
            export?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
                
                if export!.status.rawValue == 4 {
                    self.vwLoader.removeFromSuperview()
                    return
                }
                
                
                let documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
                let myDocumentPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("temp.mp4").absoluteString
                _ = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: myDocumentPath)
                let documentsDirectory2 = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as URL
                let filePath = documentsDirectory2.appendingPathComponent("video.mp4")
                self.deleteFile(filePath: filePath as NSURL)
                
                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: myDocumentPath) {
                    do { try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: myDocumentPath)
                    } catch let error {
                        self.vwLoader.removeFromSuperview()
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
```

```
//THIS FUNCTION IS USE AFTER I SAVE FILTERED VIDEO
                self.addWatermarkToVideo(inputURL: savedoutputURL, outputURL: filePath) { success in
                    if (success != nil) {
                        print("Watermark applied and video exported successfully.")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            
                            VideoEditorClass().deleteFile(savedoutputURL)
                            self.vwLoader.removeFromSuperview()
                            let vc = shareVC(nibName: "shareVC", bundle: nil)
                            vc.videourl = success
                            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
                            self.present(vc, animated: true)
                        }
                    } else {
                        VideoEditorClass().deleteFile(savedoutputURL)
                        self.vwLoader.removeFromSuperview()
                        self.showAlert(title: "Alert!", message: "Failed to export video", viewController: self)
                        print("Failed to apply watermark or export video.")
                    }
                }
                
            })
        }


func addWatermarkToVideo(inputURL: URL, outputURL: URL, completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            
            let videoAsset = AVAsset(url: inputURL)
            
            let composition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
            composition.renderSize = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first?.naturalSize ?? CGSize.zero
            
            composition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
            
            let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
            instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: videoAsset.duration)
            
            let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!)
            
            // Get the video orientation from the first video track
            let videoTransform = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0].preferredTransform
            layerInstruction.setTransform(videoTransform, at: .zero)
            
            let videoSize = composition.renderSize
            
            let parentlayer = CALayer()
            let videoLayer = CALayer()
            let watermarkLayer = CALayer()
            let overlayLayer = CALayer()
            
            
            watermarkLayer.contents = tempImageView.asImage().cgImage
            overlayLayer.contents = imgOverlay.asImage().cgImage
            
            parentlayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: videoSize)
            videoLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: videoSize)
            watermarkLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: videoSize)
            overlayLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: videoSize)
            
            parentlayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
            parentlayer.addSublayer(overlayLayer)
            parentlayer.addSublayer(watermarkLayer)
            
            composition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentlayer)
            
            instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
            composition.instructions = [instruction]
            
            guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: videoAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
            exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
            exportSession.videoComposition = composition
            
            exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
                switch exportSession.status {
                case .completed:
                    completion(exportSession.outputURL)
                case .failed, .cancelled:
                    completion(nil)
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in Advance